# Python OpenCV convert image to byte string

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

```
image = camera.read()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

When I'm starting a program - got this:

```
Traceback:
    File "file", line 55, in <module>
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
TypeError: src is not a numerical tuple
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: you need to add more information about your image `image`and the rest of your code ...

Comment: http://www.ex.ua/load/131174966 - File with part of code

Comment: sorry, I don't understand Russian!

Comment: this is a link with py script. Only Ukrainian Hosting :)

Answer (score 2):

I think camera.read() returns a tuple, the first element being a bool and the next element is the frame itself.

so try this:

```
ret, image = camera.read()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

Comment: fyi, here's a link that may be helpful to you:  http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of cvtColor , probably your structure is wrong, check the structure of your `image`

[link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html)

> Parameters:
>
> ```
> src – input image: 8-bit unsigned, 16-bit unsigned ( CV_16UC... ), or single-precision floating-point.
> ```